# Ranking Keywords in Sharepoint

Tags: search

Is there a way to rank keywords in Sharepoint? For example, when someone types mouse i want them to go to portal.hunz.com/officesupplies first, when someone types notebook then they will go to portal.hunz.com/computing

If possible, then how to do configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keywords link in the Site Collection Administration settings for the search site.  Add keywords and best bets for those terms and they'll appear as a best bet when searched for.

Comment: Do I need to do a full crawl? Do I set up the keywords at the web-application level (portal.foo.com)? or individual site collection level (like, portal.foo.com/sites/officesupplies or portal.foo.com/sites/computing)?

Comment: No, you don't need to crawl, when using best bets/keywords.

Comment: I added movie tickets, gym in the keyword and using same best bet. when do a search in the portal the site dont even come up from the portal search.