# searching by best bets is still pending

Tags: search-results

[Ranking Keywords in Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16584/ranking-keywords-in-sharepoint)

I configured and added keywords what wat suggested in the above post. However, when I do a search (even after incremental crawl) the preferred site is not showing up at all (not even on the first page). It should be the first item on the search result.

What else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search best bets are in a separate web part on the search results page.  Edit the page and look to see if there's a Search Best Bets web part.  If not, click the Add a Web Part heading in the area where you'd like it and select it from the list of seach web parts.

Comment: Yes, best bet webpart is present in the result.aspx page and i can see the wp. however, the result for best bet is blank.

Comment: So at portal.foo.com, when users search, are they being directed to portal.foo.com/SearchCenter (or something similar)?  Are the best bets defined at http://portal.foo.com/_layouts/listkeywords.aspx and pointed to a site collection the users have permission to?

Comment: no, the best bets are defined at the another site collection but under the same web app (portal.foo.com)

Comment: Eric: I think I got the idea. I put the keyword at the portal.foo.com site and now its doing the magic.

Comment: Great, glad we got it sorted out!